# Mixin in SCSS (properties of a class inside another one)

Tags: sass, less, scss-mixins

In LESS I could write something like:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}

.boo {
    .foo();
    background: blue;
}
```

To "include" properties of `.foo` class into `.boo` one.

*What is the easiest and clean way to obtain a similar beaviour in SCSS?*

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this,

mixins.scss

```
@mixin flex($x: center, $y: center) {
    display: flex;
    align-items: $x;
    justify-content: $y;
}
```

custom.scss

```
.classname {
    @include flex(flex-start, space-between);
    color: red;
}
```

Use @include

Comment: It seems that in SCSS is necessary to specifically create a mixin, instead of simplet and cleaner approach of LESS in which any CSS class could become a mixing without specific declaration...

Comment: @LucaDetomi if he answered your question the way you wanted, please check the checkmark next to his answer